# Facebook share button coming up with wrong app id

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-sharer

I've been adding the following code to my site in order to create a facebook share button.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1417490015165574";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.hazemagazine.co.uk/example-of-sharer-    2" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

In there my app id is 1417490015165574 - when i click on the share button though the app id in the URL is different. Here's an example http://www.hazemagazine.co.uk/example-of-sharer-2

I'm not the most technically competent person so any help would be most appreciated!!

Comment: You're calling/requesting Facebook `all.js` twice in your page and none of the sends the parameter `appId` (both are set to "{your_app_id}", plus a meta data has that, too stick to one `FB.init();` I believe that the app id (309437425817038) in `sharer.php` is a Facebook app (belongs to them) and its name is  **Widget Share Log App**

Answer (score 2):

use FB.init

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '{your-app-id}',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did this but it did not work. Here is an example you can see... http://www.hazemagazine.co.uk/sharer-example-3 - going crazy with this one...i imagine it is something to do with the javascript in my theme but have no idea!!

Comment: im unable to find the SHARE button on page, after reviewing you source code you are using JS SDK in meta tags in head section for two times (remove it) also add OG app id tag in head section

Comment: im unable to find the SHARE button on page (strange not loading on chrome and firefox, though loading in Tor Browser!!!), after reviewing you source code you are using JS SDK in meta tags in head section for two times (remove it) also add OG app_id tag in head section, the sharer is using app_id of 'Widget Share Log App' it hink you are using wp plugin, view in the setting of plugin also